# Accessing key names in JSON array

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I need to access key names in JSON array inside my handle template. My JSON array look like following.

```
    {
   "attributes":[
      {
         "name":"malintha"
      },
      {
         "age":"29"
      },
      {
         "marks":"81"
      }
   ]
}
```

Following is my handlebar template. I need to access key values and also values of related keys.

```
    {{#attributes}}
        <{{#key}}>{{#value}}</{{#key}}>
    {{/attributes}}
```

Expected output is

```
    <name>malintha</name>
    <age>29</age>
    <marks>81</marks>
```

But I am not getting the expected output. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [`#each`](https://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#iteration) function, and iterate your JSON array.

Then you must iterate every property in your object, using the same function and use the `@key` to access the property name:

```
{{#each attributes}}
  {{#each this}}
    <{{@key}}>{{this}}</{{@key}}>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment added later, I'll change this answer to, "check out the each-in helper".

https://guides.emberjs.com/release/templates/displaying-the-keys-in-an-object/

Though I would probably still consider restructuring that "attributes" data to be a single dict (in the handler that receives it from wherever it comes from), to make "each-in" through the data more straightforward, by iterating "attributes" and using "Object.keys" to grab the keys, etc.

Comment: I need to embed my logic inside the template but not in the code

Comment: Check out https://guides.emberjs.com/release/templates/displaying-the-keys-in-an-object/